# Select few among all the nested entities : SPRING JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a scenario like below.

Lets say `EntityA` has three nested entities `EntityB, EntityC, EntityD`. And all of `EntityB, EntityC, EntityD` has several nested entities inside them.

But while selecting for `EntityA` it selects the whole tree of nested entities. Whereas I want to fetch a specific branch. Lets say only `EntityA, EntityB` and all sub entities of `EntityB` are to be fetched leaving `EntityC` and `EntityD` back then I am not sure how to do that. As spring jpa brings all the nested objects back to me.

I am using below collection mapping.

---

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "customer_party_mapping")
 @Data
 public class CustomerPartyMappingEntity {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private Integer custmerId;
    
    @Column(name = "orgtype_id")
    private Integer orgTypeId;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_party_mapping_id")
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<CustomerPartyBookingLocationEntity> customerPartyBookingLocation=new ArrayList<CustomerPartyBookingLocationEntity>();
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_party_mapping_id")
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<CustomerPartyFieldMappingEntity> customerPartyFieldMappingEntity=new ArrayList<CustomerPartyFieldMappingEntity>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_party_mapping_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<CustomerPartyOtherDocumentEntity> otherDocumentsList=new 
    ArrayList<>();
    
    @OneToOne( cascade={ CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_name_screening_id", referencedColumnName="id") 
    private CustomerNameScreeningEntity customerNameScreeningEntity;
        
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_party_mapping_id")
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    private List<CustomerDocInfoTrackingEntity> customerDocInfoTrackingList=new 
    ArrayList<CustomerDocInfoTrackingEntity>();
}
```

---

And I am calling

---

```
List<CustomerPartyMappingEntity> customerPartyMappingEntityList = customerPartyMappingRepository.findByCustmerId(customerid);
```

---

It gets all the nested mapped list of entities wheras I need only `CustomerPartyMappingEntity` and its list of `customerPartyFieldMappingEntity` nested object.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First use `FetchType.LAZY` for nested entity.
Then you can use `@EntityGraph` to fetch nested entity by name and their nested entity using their name with `.` in the repository. You use to just specify the nested property in `attributePaths` like

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"customerPartyBookingLocation"})
```

And the nested property of `customerPartyBookingLocation` like

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"customerPartyFieldMappingEntity.subField"})
```

Example:

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"customerPartyBookingLocation", "customerPartyFieldMappingEntity.subField"})
List<CustomerPartyMappingEntity> findByCustmerId(Integer customerid);
```

*Note:* You can't use @EntityGraph with @Query annotation

Comment: OK. Then if I want different combinations of nested collections to retrieve then I have to have multiple similar methods in repository? If so then I can't use derived query for root entity and has to use @Query way.. right?

Comment: You can't use `@EntityGraph` with `@Query`, you can use method naming query with `@EntityGraph`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'method naming query'. Do you mean NamedEntityGraph?

Comment: No, actually I mean [Query creation from method names](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods)

Comment: I don't see much difference between "Query creation from method names" and derived queries. They both would not be useful in the below use case. Lets say I still want to call `List<CustomerPartyMappingEntity> findByCustmerId(Integer customerid);` in five different cases where in each of the five different cases a different nested list is expected, not all at a time. So I think I should use NamedEntityGraph to achieve this. Anyway thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

If your entities are really setup correctly, see for instance the subselect example [here](https://hub.packtpub.com/advanced-fetching/) and remove your *EAGER* (you are currently instructing hibernate to fetch all these fields upon entity initialization). It should work.